# How to sum the value from a column dynamic table

Tags: javascript, html, sum

I want to sum the value of total price. I make a `sumTransaction()` function.  The table is dynamic. Then the value show up to `area_total`. But how to sum the `td` value from total price index column?

[image]

html code

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="form" style="margin-top: 50px;">

        <div class="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail3">Input</label>
                <div class="">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="transaction" placeholder="Input Transaction">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="addTransaction()">Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <table id="table_trans" class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>Total Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        <input type="button" value="Total Price" class="btn btn-success" id="sumTransaction()" />
                    </td>
                    <td id="area_total"></td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

script code

```
function addRow(tags) {
    tags = tags.split(',');
    var total = tags[1] * tags[2];
    tags.push(total);
    var theTable = document.getElementById('table_trans').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
    var newRow = theTable.insertRow(-1);
    var newCell, theText, i;
    for (i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        newCell = newRow.insertCell(i);

        theText = document.createTextNode(tags[i]);
        newCell.appendChild(theText);
    }
}

function addTransaction() {
    var inputTags = document.getElementById('transaction').value;
    addRow(inputTags);
}

function sumTransaction() {
    var td = document.getElementById('table_trans').getElementsByTagName('td');
    var total = 0;

    for (var i in td) {
        if (td[i])
            total += parseInt(td[i].innerHTML);
    }
    document.getElementById('area_total').innerHTML = total;
}
```

Comment: Can you create live working demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 1):

Now, you try to sum up all the integers (and not only integers, which results in `NaN`) in your table.

You can select all last columns of your table body using the following selector:

```
function sumTransaction()
{
    var td = document.querySelectorAll('#table_trans > tbody > tr > td:last-child');
    var total = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < td.length; i++)
    {
        total += parseInt(td[i].innerText);
    }

    document.getElementById('area_total').innerText = total;
}
```

By the way, this loop can be simplified using `Array.prototype.reduce`:

```
var total = [].reduce.call(td, function(a, b) {
    return a + parseInt(b.innerText);
}, 0);
```

Here is the working [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ykurmangaliyev/r036sr39/1/). The demo runs calculations immediately, without button click.

Comment: I think it's better to use `parseFloat()` instead of `parseInt()` just in case the the total price has fractions http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/6z7xydg7/

Answer (score 1):

In this [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpzBed?editors=101)

in the `addRow()` function I changed into this in order to add a class `total-price` to the last `td` to grab them easily later - *and you can style the total prices separately if you want* - in the `sumTransaction()` function:

```
for (i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    newCell = newRow.insertCell(i);
    if (i == 3) {
        var lastCell = theTable.lastElementChild.lastElementChild;
        lastCell.className = "total-price";
    }

    theText = document.createTextNode(tags[i]);
    newCell.appendChild(theText);
}
```

and the `sumTransaction()` function:

```
function sumTransaction() {
    var totalPrice = document.getElementsByClassName("total-price");
    var i, priceText, grandTotal = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < totalPrice.length; i++) {
        priceText = parseFloat(totalPrice[i].innerHTML);
        grandTotal += priceText;
    }
    alert(grandTotal);
}
```

```js
function addRow(tags) {
  tags = tags.split(',');
  var total = tags[1] * tags[2];
  tags.push(total);
  var theTable = document.getElementById('table_trans').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
  var newRow = theTable.insertRow(-1);
  var newCell, theText, i;
  for (i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    newCell = newRow.insertCell(i);
    if (i == 3) {
      var lastCell = theTable.lastElementChild.lastElementChild;
      lastCell.className = "total-price";
    }

    theText = document.createTextNode(tags[i]);
    newCell.appendChild(theText);
  }
}

function addTransaction() {
  var inputTags = document.getElementById('transaction').value;
  addRow(inputTags);
}

function sumTransaction() {
  var totalPrice = document.getElementsByClassName("total-price");
  var i, priceText, grandTotal = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < totalPrice.length; i++) {
    priceText = parseFloat(totalPrice[i].innerHTML);
    grandTotal += priceText;
  }
  alert(grandTotal);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="form" style="margin-top: 50px;">
    <div class="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3">Input</label>
        <div class="">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="transaction" placeholder="Input Transaction">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="addTransaction()">Add</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <table id="table_trans" class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>Total Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">
            <input type="button" value="Total Price" class="btn btn-success" onclick="sumTransaction()" />
          </td>
          <td id="area_total"></td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i was wondering how to add a class into last coloumn on the table. Because the tutorial i find always has a class on `td` table. Thanks for the answer :D

Comment: You so welcome, and I apologize I didn't know that you needed this feature too in your first question I felt guilty when i saw the second question